# Extract duplicates in unordered pairs of two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

For a given structure

```
personA  personB  text
tom       jack    hello
jack      tom    hi there
```

By using mysql, I want to group the two rows into one group, which I want to treat pairs of (a,b) and (b,a) are the same.

So when executing query like SELECT * FROM table group by (personA), then I only want get the result of

```
personA
test
```

Is there any possible sql statement that can achieve this?

Comment: . . Your results are a bit confusing, because your query has `select *` but you are only returning one column.

Comment: and where, in this example. does the value 'test' come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where personA < personB;
```

I'm not sure why you would want only one column if you are using `select *`.

If not all rows have pairs, then:

```
select t.*
from t
where personA < personB or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.personB = t.personA and t2.personA = t.personB
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I might use a least/greatest trick here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEAST(personA, personB)    AS first,
    GREATEST(personA, personB) AS second
FROM yourTable;
```